# Boolean modifier - surface vanishes

Tags: animation, modifiers, fluid-simulation

**Situation:**
I am trying to animate boiling water. I based my idea on this [youtube tutorial](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=4h6WpcvWAZo). Basically what it does is:

- Bake fluid sim of drops falling into a fluid object
- Rotate the domain by 180 degrees upside down
- Add an object edging onto the fluid objects surface (so it overlays the fluid inflows / drops
- Substract the fluid sim from the new object using boolean modifier
- Only render the new object

**Problem:**
In some frames the animation shows very weird behaviour which i can't fix. For example in frame 12, 48 and 75 the "top" surface of my "boiling water" disappears for some reason. In frame 82 everything but the surface of my "boiling water" disappears.

**What i tried so far:**

- Moving/resizing the domain: This made some of the frames work but therefore other break. I couldn't find a constellation in which all frames would be okay.
- Adding smooth modifier: This fixed it for a lot of frames and left me with the few i mentioned above
- Moving and resizing the "boiling water" object: This helped for some frames but also broke others
- Recalculating normals of all objects (inside and out): This didn't change anything
- Changing and rebaking fluid sim: Helped for some frames but broke others

**Question:**
What magical setting do i have to change to make this thing work?

**My .blend file:**
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I figured out a solution.

Changing the solver of the boolean modifier from bmesh to carve did it for me.